# Sending PHP variables with ajax and then displaying a mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, wordpress

This question might have already been asked. But I couldn't figure out how to do this.

So.. in the url I have example.com/get-coupon.php?id=288 this is a post id from a custom post type in wordpress.

What I want to do, is send this ID to an other file that makes a db query using this ID to return a coupon code. But I only want it to make this query and display the code, when the visitor presses a button.

My current get-coupon.php:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<button id="getcode">Get Your Code</button>

<div id="resultip"></div>

<script>

$('#getcode').click(function(e) {

var pID = '<?php $_GET['id'] ?>';

    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'coupon.php', 
        data: { id:  pID },
        success: function(response) {
            content.html(id);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And my coupon.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
include('wp-load.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'coupon', 'p' => $id );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$coupon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true  );
echo $coupon;
```

And again, I'd like to pass the ID variable from the URL to the query file.

Comment: in `coupon.php` change `$id = $_GET['id'];` to `$id = $_POST['id'];` as you are using `$.ajax({type: 'POST',` (and delete 1 of them, as you have 2 `$id = $_GET['id'];`).

Comment: @Sean Still not return anything.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console to see it the ajax if firing, and what is returned? Also, what is `content` from `content.html(id)`? Shouldn't that be `$('#resultip').html(response);`?

Comment: So... now the id passes to the coupon.php. But for some reason the query isn't happening

Comment: Okay, I got it working. Thanks, Sean